# Excel Formula For Re-arranging Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, worksheet-function

I have got a bit stuck with trying to make a formula in Excel, and last time I asked a question here I got great help, I have come back again. At the moment I have column A with sets of product id's. There are just under 2000. What I need to try and do is have each number showing in another column repeated 16 times, and then in the next column have the 1st 16 numbers each repeated in sequence in each of the 16 numbers in the previous column, and once those 16 are done, have the next 16 repeated the same over the next 16 sets.

Ie.

1---1---1
2---1---2
3---1---3
4---1---4
5---1---5
6---2---1
7---2---2
8---2---3
9---2---4
10--2---5

etc, but over 16 sets of numbers instead of 5. Is this possible? I am sure it is, but am stuck in a brain freeze at the moment.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the middle column can be calculated
with a formula something like:

```
=QUOTIENT( A1 , max_product_id )
```

and the right column can be calculated with a formula like:

```
=1+MOD( A1 , max_product_id )
```

where "max_product_id" is the name of a named cell containing the value 16,
and the relative reference "A1" is tweaked to refer to the cell in the same row in the left column.
After the top row is set up right,
you "pull down" those two cells and the relative reference should automagically do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer generates undesirably when I try it. Here's a simpler solution that works as I think you are asking.

I am NOT assuming the product ID's in column A (let's say) begin with "1":  let them begin however they begin. Set the column up with them. Then enter a "1" in each of the two cells to the first one's right. Let's say that's B1 and C1.

Column B in this example will the the ordinal numbers for each set of 16 product ID's. As asked for, those will begine with 1. If you desire them to begin with a different number, enter that different number in cell B1.

Now enter the following formula in cell B2:

```
=IF(C1=16,B1+1,B1)
```

It looks to see if the cell ABOVE and to the RIGHT of it, cell C1 in this example, is "16" and if it is, it knows a new set of 16 product ID's begins on that row so it adds 1 to the last ordinal number used. This is how you get that set of numbers to go up by 1 for each set of 16 product ID's.

Then go to cell C2 and enter the following formula:

```
=IF(C1=16,1,C1+1)
```

It looks to see if the cell right above it, cell C1 in this example, contains "16" and if it does, it starts the numbering over at 1. If it did not, it adds 1 to whatever is right above it continuing to build up toward 16.

This is how you get them to rise up to 16 then begin over with 1.

There are a LOT of other ways to be slick about what you need, but they all involve funny little things that you have to account for, complicating the formulas OR they limit you, making you start product ID's with "1" perhaps, or requiring the product ID;'s to all be numerical strings, no letters or other characters allowed, or requiring you to start on row 1 or have to do extra, and sometimes pretty tricky things to start o n some other row. These formulas also allow you to use them wherever you wish:  they do not have to be in the two columns immediately next to the product ID's.

I'm a bit late probably to be of use to you, but maybe someone else will search and get this as a result and find it of use.